# Unity3d Dungeon generation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I,m creating a dungeon generator in unity3d. I have a pile of prefabs(rooms, corridors, junctions). Randomly a piece is chosen for starting piece and then depending on the connecting rules next pieces are chosen. Also the dungeon can be multi layered. Like 1 room above the other etc. Problem is room collisions. On the same layer 2 rooms can be placed on top of each other and this is a problem.

My first idea was to use arrays to model the layers and then find best suiting locations for stairs up and down. But the problem with this is that not all angles are 90degrees. I have a 3 way intersection in the shape of Y. So everything that comes after this is angled. And its not easily represented on array.

Second idea was the use of collisions and backtracing. I place the tile and then if no collision I can move forward. But if collides I try to find a better suiting piece or remove the previous piece and but something new there. But I can't figure out a good method to do this.

Anyone have any suggestions or ideas on how to generate multilayered dungeons with non 90 degree angles?

Comment: What do you mean by "And its not easily represented on array."? Have you also tried using `List`'s?

Comment: @Hristo Ok an example. Lets say i have 10X10 array. Whitch represents 10X10 tiles in the game world. Room is 2X2 tiles. I can easily but the room on the array if it is axis aligned. But if i rotate the room about 60 degrees, How do i represent it on the array? Array would be a simple way to remove collision and its only really good for axis aligned tiles. Unless i have like 1000X1000 array where 5X5 represents a tile in gameworld.

Comment: That is what I meant by using a `List`. In it you could store the `GameObject` Room/Corridor/Whatever. The `GameObject` that you store would have your desired rotation, say 60' or 65', does not matter.

Comment: @Hristo but how does it help me to eliminate overlaps ?

Comment: Well if you know the position of the first `GameObject`, say its at 0,0. Then you know the dimensions of the `GameObject` (lets say 3 by 3), then you know the position of the next object would be 0,3. If that makes sense.

Comment: Well yea. Currently its like this. I have a placeholder where the next object should connect to. So dungeon generation part is done. Now what the issue is that i can get rooms and corridors that collide but should not collide. So i need a way to remove the collisions.

Comment: You could detect collision and if any just move the object by 1 and detect collision again.